# I'm tryin' to build my own fuzz but when I plug it in my amp it just makes too much noise

Tags: breadboard, distortion, guitar-pedal

[image][image]If you need the schematic, just tell me and I'll draw it for you as soon as I'm home again.

Anyway, it consists of 3 transistor stages with the first one having the boost control by regulating emitter resistance. Each stage is a simple common emitter design,and the last one has a diode as feedback between collector and base to further clip the waveform.

So, when I test it using Waveforms it does work just fine, then I tested it with the guitar as an input and the output to an oscilloscope: found out it makes much noise,the same noise I can hear in the speaker connected to my computer (so I'd say it is something in my house and the pickups sense it).

To try and avoid it, I used the same oscilloscope to understand what frequencies this noise has, and since they range between 8kHz and 12kHz, I simply put a low-pass filter (simple passive one) with cut-off frequency at 4kHz so that the signal to the amplifier can remain almost unaltered.

At the oscilloscope now everything seems fine (just guitar signal from strings and no more noise superimposed). But when I connect the circuit output to the amplifier the noise is there again and massive too (it's so much that its volume is greater than the string's).

How could I get around this?

Keep in mind that I'm using a breadboard since I would like to be sure that the circuit is working correctly before soldering it, but other times using the same breadboard worked out just fine to test other circuits.

Could it be faulty design? But then even if it's so, why does everything seem fine at the oscilloscope?

Comment: The schematic is essential and maybe an in-focus, well-cropped photo of the setup.

Comment: Ok done. I don't remember if the last transistor is A92 or A42, anyway the NPN one of the two, the other one is PNP and I made sure it was NPN

Comment: A simple test is to short out the input and see if the noise is all generated by the circuit.

Comment: Solderless breadboards are usually really bad for analog circuits. Easier said than done, but I'd try changing to a soldered breadboard so your connections are solid.

Comment: The black supply wire is connected to left red positive rail. The red supply wire is connected to right red positive rail. Yet, there are connections to the non-connected blue supply rails. Either the circuit is built wrong, or it's just difficult to see how they are wired.

Comment: The breadboard is probably at least partially at fault here. What's a fuzz, anyway?

Comment: @Hearth   It's a distortion pedal.  Guitarists are probably the only people who not only don't try to eliminate distortion, we embrace it.   Generally they're pretty simple - You just drive your signal until it clips at the rails (or use diodes, etc...)   Done right, you get 
 harmonics which are musically related to the root tone.  i.e.  You play an "E" note, you will also hear "B" and "G" as overtones.   Done wrong, it's horrible.  "Fuzz" is a subset of distortion pedals.   Think early 70's hard rock.

Comment: What are you using for a power supply????    If it's a wall-wort or some other 'modern' thing, try again with a 9V battery.   And put a big capacitor across your power rail.. like 100uF at least  (From 9V to GND)

Comment: @KyleB I understand how distortion works and how it's used for making interesting sounds (I promise you it's not just guitarists who do this, look at any analog synthesizer!), I just didn't know what "a fuzz" means.

Comment: @Hearth   Fair enough :)  In the future I shall expand that comment to "musicians". // "Fuzz Face" was the original.   If you happen to have one of these, you have something that can be sold for a couple thousand $$$.   I know, nuts right?    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_Face [Edited by a moderator.]

Comment: @Justme yeah it's difficult to see how stuff's wired, I at least triple-check that every time I move something (because of bad past experience). Also, the resistances I bought have very loose pins that's why they're so twisted